# cURL executed twice when file_get_contents is run?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, file-get-contents

I've run into a very strange issue. I am calling an API over cURL. I collect some information (request, headers, response, cookies etc.) and then if test mode is on I used to print it out to the browser initially. Then, after the initial tests, I decided to log to file, so the echoing doesn't interfere with ajax calls etc. I am using file_get_contents / file_put_contents to just save the log to a text file on the server. But when I do, the curl requests are executed twice for some reason! When I switch to echo again - they only execute once. The only other way to prevent double calling is if the cURL function is run before the pageheaders are sent and I cal die() immediately after??? Thus, when ajax is run - no double calls.

For example, I have a situation where I run two API calls one after the other. They don't duplicate as A A B B, but as A B A B.

What I've checked:

- the class method is only called the correct number of times ( simple `echo 'test';` )
- `curl_exec` is not duplicated in the code
- removing the saving to file bit removes the duplication

Here are the two parts of my code

CURL:

```
$headers= [
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Accept: application/json',
  'Api-Layer: '.$request['apilayer'],
];

$url = $this->server . $request['api'];

$ch = curl_init();      

$options = [
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,  
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => FALSE,    
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,  
        CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,  
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 6,  
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 6, 
];

$options[CURLOPT_POST] = TRUE;
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $request['post'];
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;

$cookies = [];
if (isset($_COOKIE['COOKIENAME'])) {
    $cookies[] = 'COOKIENAME ='.$_COOKIE['COOKIENAME'];
}

$options[CURLOPT_COOKIE] = implode(';', $cookies); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 
session_write_close();
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);     

$headers = substr($data, 0, $curl_info['header_size']);
$body = substr($data, $curl_info['header_size']);

curl_close($ch);
session_start();

preg_match('/Set-Cookie: COOKIENAME=([^\n;]*)\b/',$headers, $cookie1);
if (!empty($cookie1[1])) {
    $this->createCookie('COOKIENAME',$cookie1[1]);
}

$response = [
    'http_code' => $curl_info['http_code'],
    'body' => $body,
];

if ($this->test) {
    $this->addToLog($headers , 'RESPONSE_HEADERS');
    $this->addToLog($body, 'RESPONSE_BODY');
    $this->addToLog($curl_info, 'CURL_GETINFO');
}

return $response;
```

and then a bit later the log is printed:

```
public function printLog() {

    $file = PATH_TO_DIR.'api_log.txt';  
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= $this->apiLog;
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
    $this->apiLog = '';
}
```

What am I missing???

EDIT: Could it be htaccess issue? I'm runing a regular MAMP stack from bitnami

Comment: Are you positively sure that the script that calls `printLog()` only calls it once and only gets called once?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter anyway - the responses from the API calls are different, which means it's not duplication of the log only, there are multiple curl calls!